# 'match.path' is missing in props validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, eslint

I want to creat a function that returns a `Switch`.

**My custom switch**

```
  const breadcrumbsSwitch = () => {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}/first`} component={First} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/second`} component={Second} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
```

However I am getting the error:

> 'match.path' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types)

I am not sure why this occurs only when I extract my Switch into a function.
If I write the switch directly into my component, without the function, es-lint does not complain.

Comment: It's some kind of naïve textual validation that doesn't understand the semantics and doesn't use static type information. It probably just decides to flag you for factoring your code in a way it hadn't thought of. You're using TypeScript so you don't need to care about that rule. If you don't specify a `path`, TS will give you an error.